# iOS universal link does not work on one device (although works on other iOS devices)

Tags: ios, ios-universal-links

I'm facing a strange issue with universal links on iPhone - iOS 12.2.
I'm trying to open the APP using a registered universal link (the same link works on other devices using both - the same and different version of iOS), using identical application (the same version).

What's strange is that I can't even find the option to open the link in a native app when holding the link for a while on this device, although I found it in other devices.
It used to work, but then suddenly stopped to open the APP. I tried rebooting and reinstalling the app.

Did anyone face similar issue? Any suggestion in debugging? I'd really like to avoid factory reset of the phone.

Comment: Have a look please. Question 1) Did you test it http or https ? Must i have to test it with https site ? Question 2) i have set the link like applinks:mywebsite.com.au and implement continue userActivity: in appdelegate. Question 3)  my json data in aasa file is : {    "applinks": {  "apps": [], "details": [ { "appID": "TeamID.BundleID",  "paths": ["*", "/"] } ] }}When i click it from mail app with domain.com.au or https://domain.com.au , it open safari. It's not opening my app. I tested in iPhone 6s plus, iOS 12.2. What could be the possible problem ?

Comment: 1) Yes, HTTPS - Said it works on other iOS devices, except this one

2) Sure

3) Sure

The problem is not with settings. It **works** on other devices. The problem is with the device itself (the settings there) - But I couldn't find anyone having the same issue, that's why I asked. So once again: It worked, then it stopped. But only on **this** device. Other devices works. But the option is not there even when holding the link, whereas on other I see "Open in {{appname}}".

Comment: I know this is not going to help, but I read somewhere (I need to find it) that this was an issue with iOS 12.2 or Branch or something. I am having this same problem. If I find the solution, I will post it here.

Comment: @Matty We are currently facing same issue . After upgrading to 12.2 our universal link stoppped working. But its still working on 12.1 and lower versions .Can u share how did u solve it ?

Comment: @BrandonTripp If you can share the link where this information is availble, it will be great help

Comment: any updates on this? Did you manage to fix it?

Comment: So after upgrading to the newest iOS the problem still remained in Chrome.

I was able to open the contextual menu and open the app through the `Open in...` item from **Safari**, and since then it works as expected across all the browsers. This doesn't explain the origin of this issue, but I hope this will help you as well.

Answer (score 1):

You might be running into either of these two bugs:
https://openradar.appspot.com/45201697
https://openradar.appspot.com/33893852

I just ran into this. Deleting the app, reboot the device, wait an hour or so (unsure of time needed to wait) then reinstall the app. That seems to force it to re-check the AASA.

Seems like there could be a process running after reboot blocking `swcd` from running.

Comment: Yes, that's it. You don't have to wait an hour, a minute or so is enough

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to delete the app and restart the phone to check if this is not a `apple-app-site-association` problem?

Comment: Yes, I did, the app was deleted, and the phone restarted. But no change.
Also, as I mentioned - the APP is successfully opened in other iOS devices. So it is not an issue with `apple-app-site-association` file.

Answer (score 0):

So after upgrading to the newest iOS the problem still remained in Chrome.

I was able to open the contextual menu and open the app through the `Open in...` item from **Safari**, and since then it works as expected across all the browsers. This doesn't explain the origin of this issue, but I hope this will help you as well.